# Load XML File in PHP and add Child if not exists

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, addattribute

i want to load XML data into my php file with address data.
Each address should also have coordinates - if not they should be added. So i am doing the following:

```
        $xmlDatei = "AddressData.xml";
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlDatei);

        for($i=0,$size=count($xml);$i<$size;$i++){

            if($xml->RECORD[$i]->ADDRESS->LAT != NULL){
                //get lat and lng stuff here...

                $lat = .......
                $lng = .......


                echo "lat: " . $lat; // Test echo WORKING
                echo "lng: " . $lng;

                // Now i want to add the data to the xml
                $xml->RECORD[$i]->ADDRESS->addAttribute('LAT', $lat);
                $xml->RECORD[$i]->ADDRESS->addAttribute('LNG', $lng);

                $xml->saveXML();
            }

            // Test echo NOT WORKING
            echo $xml->RECORD[$i]->ADDRESS->LAT;
            echo $xml->RECORD[$i]->ADDRESS->LNG;
        }
```

So it seems like the addAttribute is not working properly here.

What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your echo is looking for a child *element* called `LAT`:

```
echo $xml->RECORD[$i]->ADDRESS->LAT;
```

But you have added an *attribute*, so you need to use different syntax:

```
echo $xml->RECORD[$i]->ADDRESS['LAT'];
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response
this is working for my echo now. but its still not appearing in my xml document???

Comment: @TimDöring Do you mean the output of `$xml->saveXML();`? Note that that doesn't save the output to a file, it's [just an alias of `->asXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.savexml.php).

Answer (score 0):

You are adding attributes to the `ADDRESS` tag, not nodes.

Try this:

```
echo $xml->RECORD[$i]->ADDRESS['LAT'];
echo $xml->RECORD[$i]->ADDRESS['LNG'];
```

Comment: Pass the filename by which you want to save the xml file in `saveXML()`. `$xml->saveXML(YOUR_XML_FILE_NAME);`